# Unable to mount any ISO images

Tags: arch-linux, mount, iso

I'm running Arch Linux with kernel version 4.0.7-2 and I am unable to mount any ISO images whatsoever. I downloaded the Arch live image and the command

```
mount archlinux-2015.08.01-dual.iso /media/iso
```

gives the following error:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

while `dmesg | tail` gives me this:

```
[   52.673710] wlp6s0: authenticated
[   52.676747] wlp6s0: associate with 0a:18:d6:4f:b1:d4 (try 1/3)
[   52.678936] wlp6s0: RX AssocResp from 0a:18:d6:4f:b1:d4 (capab=0x421 status=0 aid=6)
[   52.679383] wlp6s0: associated
[   56.484939] ksplashqml[605]: segfault at 208 ip 00007f6712264552 sp 00007fff6edf4bb0 error 4 in i965_dri.so[7f6711e91000+592000]
[   92.663397] scsi 5:0:1:0: CD-ROM            CDEmu    Virt. CD/DVD-ROM 1.10 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[   92.666524] sr 5:0:1:0: [sr2] scsi3-mmc drive: 48x/48x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[   92.666882] sr 5:0:1:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr2
[  657.598116] perf interrupt took too long (2522 > 2495), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50100
[  892.225255] loop: module loaded
```

This doesn't change even after repeatedly executing the command, so it's safe to say it doesn't actually write anything in the syslog.

Executing `fuseiso archlinux-2015.08.01-dual.iso /media/iso` gives me

```
init: wrong standard identifier in volume descriptor 0, skipping..
init: wrong standard identifier in volume descriptor 1, skipping..
init: wrong standard identifier in volume descriptor 2, skipping..
init: wrong standard identifier in volume descriptor 3, skipping..
init: wrong standard identifier in volume descriptor 4, skipping..
init: wrong standard identifier in volume descriptor 5, skipping..
init: wrong standard identifier in volume descriptor 6, skipping..
init: wrong standard identifier in volume descriptor 7, skipping..
init: wrong standard identifier in volume descriptor 8, skipping..
init: wrong standard identifier in volume descriptor 9, skipping..
init: wrong standard identifier in volume descriptor 10, skipping..
init: wrong standard identifier in volume descriptor 11, skipping..
init: wrong standard identifier in volume descriptor 12, skipping..
init: wrong standard identifier in volume descriptor 13, skipping..
init: wrong standard identifier in volume descriptor 14, skipping..
init: wrong standard identifier in volume descriptor 15, skipping..
init: wrong standard identifier in volume descriptor 16, skipping..
init: wrong standard identifier in volume descriptor 17, exiting..
```

Finally, executing `mount -o loop -t auto archlinux-2015.08.01-dual.iso /media/iso` gives the same error as above, but it actually adds the following error to dmesg:

```
UDF-fs: warning (device loop1): udf_fill_super: No partition found (2)
```

And this happens no matter what kind of ISO image I try to mount. Anyone have any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

It could be a permission problem on the .iso file; check if you own the file.
You can use ls -l  command (list information about the FILEs) to find out the file / directory owner and group names.

Also, related to the mount command, you can always specify the filesystem type:

```
mount -t iso9660 archlinux-2015.08.01-dual.iso /media/iso
```

Fuseiso isn't designed to work on an already mounted file. Try to unmount the file:

```
umount /media/iso  ( or force unmount with: umount -f /media/iso )
```

and than execute again the command:

```
fuseiso archlinux-2015.08.01-dual.iso /media/iso
```

**Later edit**

I was curious about the file format, so I downloaded the same arch distro file and mounted on my RHEL 6.6 with the following command:

```
mount -t iso9660 -o loop /file_location/archlinux-2015.08.01-dual.iso /media/iso
```